# Getting ref of parent component from nested child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i access the parent component div ref from nested child component.

**App.js**

```
const appRef = useRef()

  <div ref={appRef}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path="/products">
          <Products />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Products.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.props.innerRef) // undefined 
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <PopUp />
    )
  }
```

**PopUp.js**

```
const PopUp = forwardRef(function PopUp(props,ref){
    console.log(ref) // null 
    console.log(ref?.current?.offsetWidth) // undefined
  })
```

Comment: Pass the ref to the child as a prop? `<Products appRef={appRef} />` and then `<PopUp appRef={appRef} />`. Using a `forwardRef` is when you want to use `<PopUp ref={appRef} />`.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need a ref to the parent component? That sounds...problematic... :-) From the code it looks like you're trying to use the parent's `offsetWidth`, but beware that the parent may well not be rendered (your code will get `undefined`) at that point, and the width of the parent can change without re-rendering occurring.

Comment: Because i need to set the width of my pop according to the appRef div width, so to calculate that

Comment: @dev - Yes, I'd updated my comment above. If that's the reason, I would recommend not doing it that way, it will be fragile. Instead, use CSS. If for some reason that's not feasible, have the parent pass the width as a prop and watch for resize events so you can re-render if needed.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const width = document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0].offsetWidth;
    setWidth(`${width}px`);
  }, [size]);

So what i was doing is this ^^ in my PopUp component I am using createPortal to achieve the PopUp

Comment: In order of doing document.getElementsByClassName i was trying to target the parent  div using ref, but I wasn't. So what would be the right way Because I have around 8 to 9 routes, and only in Products Page - PopUp only required the dynamic calculation of width

Comment: @T.J.Crowder passing as prop which @ evolutionbox suggested should I do it in that way ? or without drilling down prop in multiple component is there a way ?

Comment: @dev - I wouldn't use a ref for this at all. As I said above, I'd have the parent provide the width (and watch for the width changing).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239352/discussion-between-dev-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @evolutionxbox need a solution for typescript